# Angular material - Unexpected behavior when splitting code into component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a simple angular page with right side nav of angular material.
when I write all the code on app-component everything works as expected, the navbar opens aside from the toolbar and the main page as expected.
see [Demo As Expected](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-m7okqq)
But when I tried to split the app-root into component the side nav float on the toolbar, not as mode="side" of navbar should do.
see [Demo Not As Expected](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-dzdxny?file=app%2Fmain-menu%2Fmain-menu.component.html)

I tried to play with CSS / add fxFlex but the behavior still the same

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you mean to the `estate-name`?

Comment: yes, too.
I want that all the screen move aside when the navbar will open.
as documented in the navbar on "mode"=side attribute. [see](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api)
it works well on the first demo that I sent.

Comment: that what do you mean:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-gq3wbx?file=app%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.css

Comment: This one is not working well.
the sidenav appear on the toolbar and hide the title.
it should :
1.  to show the title.
2. to push the toolbar when its open

Comment: Please do not link to sample code outside of stackoverflow. Links are volatile and might not exist in the future. Instead, please isolate the problem that you want to solve and ask it in the question in detail.

Comment: @EzriY see now:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-gq3wbx?file=app%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html

Comment: Works perfect, many thanks. @לבני מלכה

Comment: I will post answer to explain you why it happend

Comment: @לבנימלכה it will be blessed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use more component means that more `div` wrap your code...

This "additional" div bother to the noraml behavior of `mat-sidenav`

[image]

So the trick is to exlude only `<mat-sidenav>` to the main component(in your case `sidenav-autosize-example`) and the content put in the new component (in your case `<app-main-menu></app-main-menu>`)

Also use [`:host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()) in `sidenav-autosize-example` css to style the content of child component.

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-gq3wbx?file=app%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html)

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" fullscreen autosize>
  <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav" mode="side" position="end" opened="true">
    <app-main-menu></app-main-menu>
  </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: tell me for more explaintions

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related with the Angular Material elements hierarchy.

When you create a component, Angular puts another HTML tag between the parent component and the child component, with the child component name. Changing the code like below, the Side Nav works.

As the Side Nav element influences the parent element orientation, I think it have to be placed right after a `<mat-sidenav-container`> element.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" fullscreen autosize>
 <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav" mode="side" position="end" opened="true">
    <app-main-menu></app-main-menu>
  </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```